# Why can't one overdose on zinc by eating zinc-rich food such as oysters?

Tags: digestion, micronutrients, toxicity, zinc, mechanism-of-action

I've come across [the following statement](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/zinc-overdose-symptoms):

> Although some foods contain zinc well above the UL of 40 mg per day, no cases of zinc poisoning from naturally occurring zinc in food have been reported.

According to the [Zinc deficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc_deficiency) article in Wikipedia,

> Oysters, cooked, breaded and fried, 3 ounces (about 5 average sized oysters) - Zinc content - 74.0 mg

This is way above what a standard supplement dose (10 mg) contains, and a person can easily consume 300 grams of oysters a day, which will bring his zinc consumption to above 200 mg/day.

What are the mechanisms that prevent a person from [zinc toxicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc_toxicity) in such cases?

Comment: Well that is not the normal diet for most people. You can also search for the copper content of the oyster. It seems rather high as far as food goes, https://nutritiondata.self.com/foods-015125000000000000000.html?maxCount=49 and this may help ameliorate all that zinc. Whereas with a single mineral zinc supplement we are getting just zinc.

Comment: Copper/zinc ratio by an RD:  https://susanmacfarlanenutrition.com/understanding-nutrient-ratios-zinccopper/

Comment: More information NIH:  https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/Zinc-HealthProfessional/

Comment: @Gordon - Comments are for refining the question or answer, not to provide answers. You have some good information there, why not write it up into an answer?